# Move the <li> tags to their respective <ul> based on <ul>'s dynamic ID

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a list of dynamic two leveled side, but I am stuck in find the way to bind the li inside their respective ul based on ID.

As the usual, I retrieved all the data required to form a dynamic side leveled menu, the menu will be placed inside a div id called "accordion", the name of  menuID without the parentID will be set as h3, followed by the div tags to cover the ul with its ID

The menuID with the parentID will be set inside the li based on their parent ID of ul. However it seems to be ended with the li created outside the ul.

Below will be my PopulateMenu() function

```
private void PopulateMenu(DataTable dt, string Lvl4, MenuItem parentMenuItem)
    {
        string currentPage = Path.GetFileName(Request.Url.AbsolutePath);



        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {

            string url = Convert.ToString(row["fullPath"]);
            url = url.Replace(">", "/");
            HtmlGenericControl h3 = new HtmlGenericControl("h3");
            HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
            HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
            HtmlGenericControl anchor = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
            HtmlGenericControl ul = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");


//This are the expression to produce the value to be compare with the ID of the menu to see whether they will be parent or child menu item.

            string ComparePageID = row["PageID"].ToString();
            string CompareLvl3 = "0000";
            string CompareLvl4 = CompareLvl3.Replace("0000", "");

            if (ComparePageID.Contains(CompareLvl3))
            {
                h3.InnerText = row["Description"].ToString();

//I tried to use the session to save the ul id like  
//Session["sidemenu"] = row["PageID"];

                ul.Attributes.Add("id", row["PageID"].ToString());
                ul.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
                div.Attributes.Add("id", "server");
                div.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
                accordion.Controls.Add(h3);
                accordion.Controls.Add(div);
                div.Controls.Add(ul);
            }
            else
            {
                anchor.Attributes.Add("href", "~/html/" + url + ".aspx");
                anchor.Attributes.Add("id", row["PageID"].ToString());
                anchor.Attributes.Add("target", "manualmain");
                anchor.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
                anchor.InnerText = row["Description"].ToString();
                li.Controls.Add(anchor);

 //But when I use the value of Session["sidemenu"] at here to add the child item in li, error "the XXX does not exist in the current context" occurred

                accordion.Controls.Add(li);


            }


        }
    }
```

My expected output will be like

```
<h3>Parent 1</h3>
<div>
<ul id = "Somewhere0000">
    <li><a href="somewhere.aspx" id ="Somewhere0001">Child 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="somewhere2.aspx" id ="Somewhere0002">Child 2</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<h3>Parent 2</h3>
<div>
<ul id = "SomeHow0000">
    <li><a href="SomeHow.aspx" id ="SomeHow0001">Child 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="SomeHow2.aspx" id ="SomeHow0002">Child 2</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>
```

But the actual result is

```
<div id="accordion" style="width:100%; vertical-align:middle; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;">
<h3>Parent 1</h3>
<div>
<ul id = "Somewhere0000"></ul>
</div>

<li><a href="somewhere.aspx" id ="Somewhere0001">Child 1</a></li>

<li><a href="somewhere2.aspx" id ="Somewhere0002">Child 2</a></li>

<h3>Parent 2</h3>
<div>
<ul id = "SomeHow0000"></ul>
</div>              

<li><a href="SomeHow.aspx" id ="SomeHow0001">Child 1</a></li>

<li><a href="SomeHow2.aspx" id ="SomeHow0002">Child 2</a></li>

 </div>
```

So I am now finding the alternative way to push the dynamic li inside their respective dynamic ul. Whether in C# or in javascript....

Answer (score 0):

In the row `accordion.Controls.Add(li);` you add the `li` to the accordion directly. This leads to the result that you describe.

You have to add the `li` to the `ul` instead. For this to work, you need to store the last `ul` that you have created. In the following sample I have marked the relevant changes with `// >>>`

```
private void PopulateMenu(DataTable dt, string Lvl4, MenuItem parentMenuItem)
{
  string currentPage = Path.GetFileName(Request.Url.AbsolutePath);
  foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
  {
    string url = Convert.ToString(row["fullPath"]);
    url = url.Replace(">", "/");
    HtmlGenericControl h3 = new HtmlGenericControl("h3");
    HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
    HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
    HtmlGenericControl anchor = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
    // >>> Instead of generating a new ul for every row, only generate it if you add a new header
    HtmlGenericControl ul;
   //This are the expression to produce the value to be compare with the ID of the menu to see whether they will be parent or child menu item.
   string ComparePageID = row["PageID"].ToString();
   string CompareLvl3 = "0000";
   string CompareLvl4 = CompareLvl3.Replace("0000", "");
   if (ComparePageID.Contains(CompareLvl3))
   {
     h3.InnerText = row["Description"].ToString();
     //I tried to use the session to save the ul id like  
     //Session["sidemenu"] = row["PageID"];
     // >>> Create new ul only if header is created
     ul = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");
     ul.Attributes.Add("id", row["PageID"].ToString());
     ul.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
     div.Attributes.Add("id", "server");
     div.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
     accordion.Controls.Add(h3);
     accordion.Controls.Add(div);
     div.Controls.Add(ul);
   }
   else
   {
     anchor.Attributes.Add("href", "~/html/" + url + ".aspx");
     anchor.Attributes.Add("id", row["PageID"].ToString());
     anchor.Attributes.Add("target", "manualmain");
     anchor.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
     anchor.InnerText = row["Description"].ToString();
     li.Controls.Add(anchor);
     //But when I use the value of Session["sidemenu"] at here to add the child item in li, error "the XXX does not exist in the current context" occurred
     // >>> Add li to ul
     ul.Controls.Add(li);
   }
 }
```

}

---

However, the scenario that you describe can be solved much easier with using a [Repeater](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater?view=netframework-4.7.2) control. Creating controls dynamically in ASP.NET WebForms seems straightforward at first, but is really complex to make it work in every aspect. So instead of putting lots of effort in this dynamic solution, I strongly recommend to have a look at the Repeater control and how it can be used to generate the markup that you need.

Comment: Thank you for your recommend, I will put effort to figure it out

Comment: The line of code "ul.Controls.Add(li);" conducts to error use of unsigned variable "ul". Looks like I am required to find the alternative solution on repeater

Comment: @SoonFeiGreyDon please do yourself a favor and use a repeater. Once you have tried it, it is much easier than building a working solution with dynamically created controls.